# Joi validator alternative schema error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I as trying to create a Joi schema using [Joi.alternatives.try()](https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#alternativestryschemas). This is the schema I have tried.

```
Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.object({
    type: Joi.number().required().label('Error1!!')
}), Joi.object({
    reason: Joi.string().required().label('Error2!!')
})).label('Error!!')
```

This is the object that I have used.

```
{ reason: 2 }
```

I was expecting the error as `Error2!!` or something containing this the string `Error2!!`. But im getting error as

`Validation Error: "Error!!" does not match any of the allowed types`

This error comes from the parent node.

How can I make the error specific to the object? i,e, an error that comes from the alternative object node rather that the parent object.

You can use [this](https://hapi.dev/module/joi/tester/) platform to validate schema online.

**Update:**
Here is the sample schema that I used.

```
employee_retired = Joi.object({
    type: Joi.number().required().valid(2, 3, 7),
    reason: Joi.string().required()
        .min(1)
        .max(100),
    firstname: Joi.string()
        .required(),
    lastname: Joi.string()
        .required()
        .min(1)
        .max(255),
    personaldetails: Joi.alternatives().conditional('type', {
        is: 2, then: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
            address: Joi.string().required()
                .min(1)
                .max(100),
            salary: Joi.string().required()
                .min(0)
                .max(500),
            contactnumbers: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
                mobile: Joi.string().required()
                    .min(0)
                    .max(15),
                home: Joi.string()
                    .required()
                    .min(1)
                    .max(15),
            })).max(50).required(),
        }).required()).max(50).required(),
        otherwise: Joi.forbidden(),
    }),
    monthlysavings: Joi.alternatives().conditional('type', {
            is: 3,
            then: Joi.number()
                .required()
                .min(0)
                .max(50000),
            otherwise: Joi.forbidden(),
        }),
    isapproved: Joi.boolean().required(),
});

empolyee_working = Joi.object({
    type: Joi.number().required().valid(2, 3, 7),
    reason: Joi.string().required()
        .min(1)
        .max(100),
    firstname: Joi.string()
        .required(),
    lastname: Joi.string()
        .required()
        .min(1)
        .max(255),
    contactnumbers: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
        mobile: Joi.string().required()
            .min(0)
            .max(15),
        home: Joi.string()
            .required()
            .min(1)
            .max(15),
    })).max(50).required(),
    monthlysavings: Joi.alternatives().conditional('type', {
        is: 3,
        then: Joi.number().required()
            .min(1)
            .max(50000),
        otherwise: Joi.forbidden(),
    }),
    isapproved: Joi.boolean().required(),
})

const employee = Joi.alternatives().try(employee_retired, empolyee_working);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`object.or`](https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#objectorpeers-options) for this behavior:

```js
Joi.object({
    type: Joi.number().label('Error1!!'),
    reason: Joi.string().label('Error2!!')
}).or('type', 'reason').label('Error!!')
```

Tests:

```
{}
// Validation Error: "Error!!" must contain at least one of [Error1!!, Error2!!]
{ reason: 2 }
// Validation Error: "Error2!!" must be a string
{ type: "a" } // note that due to default `convert` behavior, `{ type: "2" }` would pass
// Validation Error: "Error1!!" must be a number
{ a: "b" }
// Validation Error: "a" is not allowed. "Error!!" must contain at least one of [Error1!!, Error2!!]
```

## UPDATE (after comment)

Indeed it's a bit more verbose, but follows the same logic:

- both *retired* and *working* employees share the same structure
- only `personaldetails` and `contactnumbers` vary

So something along the following lines should provide you with a precise validation error message (I haven't tested all cases though). I just "merged" both employee declarations, and the two varying cases `personaldetails` and `contactnumbers` are not declared `required` anymore but are specified in the final `or`.

```js
Joi.object({
    type: Joi.number().required().valid(2, 3, 7),
    reason: Joi.string().required()
        .min(1)
        .max(100),
    firstname: Joi.string()
        .required(),
    lastname: Joi.string()
        .required()
        .min(1)
        .max(255),
    personaldetails: Joi.alternatives().conditional('type', {
        is: 2, then: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
            address: Joi.string().required()
                .min(1)
                .max(100),
            salary: Joi.string().required()
                .min(0)
                .max(500),
            contactnumbers: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
                mobile: Joi.string().required()
                    .min(0)
                    .max(15),
                home: Joi.string()
                    .required()
                    .min(1)
                    .max(15),
            })).max(50).required(),
        // N.B.: no more .required() on the next line, .or() will handle it conditionally
        }).required()).max(50),
        otherwise: Joi.forbidden(),
    }),
    contactnumbers: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
        mobile: Joi.string().required()
            .min(0)
            .max(15),
        home: Joi.string()
            .required()
            .min(1)
            .max(15),
    // N.B.: no more .required() on the next line, .or() will handle it conditionally
    })).max(50),
    monthlysavings: Joi.alternatives().conditional('type', {
            is: 3,
            then: Joi.number()
                .required()
                .min(0)
                .max(50000),
            otherwise: Joi.forbidden(),
        }),
    isapproved: Joi.boolean().required(),
}).or('personaldetails', 'contactnumbers').label('OR failure')
```

Comment: Hi @Stock Overflaw, thanks for your response. I tried your solution and seems to working in the scenario. But the issue is like, the two objects that I mentioned in the question is not that simple like an object with a simple key. Those objects might have more than one key in which those might be an another object or an array. That's why I went for alternatives. I will update a sample object in my question that I need. I have marked an upvote for your response. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Hi @Nitheesh I just updated the answer according to the "real" case you showed. Hope this helps! :)